# Scroll through images on the web

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, event-handling

Good day everyone,

I'm kind of new to programming and I need some assistance.

Q1) I would like to create a scroll through image gallery that displays a sequence of images, having the same size and position, with a scroll bar right next to it.

For example: http://radiopaedia.org/cases/internal-carotid-artery-dissection-4

Check the link for clarification.

Q2) How to make the same process using touchscreen with on screen event handlers?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's many small questions here, and you haven't included what you've tried so far, or even what your existing knowledge is. At this point, it's fairly unanswerable; this isn't a site for requesting long tutorials.

Comment: Basically it's just about putting together `<img>` tags, so that's very simple (even most basic) HTML. The scrollbar will appear automatically. You want to read this kind of tutorials : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478181